# Windows Server 2008 R2 - RAS SSTP - HTTP 503 Service is unavailable

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, rras, sstp

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine that has the following configuration:

- It's a domain controller
- It runs IIS and serves the Default Website with HTTP bindings `0.0.0.0:80` and `[::]:80` and with HTTPS bindings `0.0.0.0:443` and `[::]:443`. The HTTPS bindings use a widely trusted X.509 / SSL certificate from NameCheap for `mydomain.com`.
- It has the RAS service installed with `mydomain.com` selected the certificate on the RAS Security property sheet. It does not have the NAP role service installed.

I cannot connect to the VPN using any Windows client. The Event Logs on the clients report receiving a HTTP 503 response from the SSTP server. I investigated by querying the SSTP endpoint directly and I received the generic (HTTP.SYS generated?) "Service is unavailable" error message. I get the same error when I access it locally.

The SSTP endpoint URI is [https://mydomain.com/sra_{BA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0ADCD75}/](https://mydomain.com/sra_%7BBA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0ADCD75%7D/)

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing this question I thought I'd take another look at the Event Logs on the server and I saw a number of `Schannel` and `RasSstp` events that I had previously overlooked.

One Event had Event ID 36888: "The following fatal alert was generated: 10. The internal error state is 1203".

Apparently code 1203 means "This event is seen on windows 2008 R2 running IIS. If a user tries to access a web site using HTTP but specifies an SSL port in the URL then this event is logged. This event is expected as the client is trying to use the wrong port or the wrong protocol to access the site".

This made me realise something I had done earlier: I set the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SstpSvc\ListenerPort` to `5000` even though IIS (or rather, HTTP.SYS) was only configured for port 443.

I reset the `ListenerPort` value to `0` (so it uses the default value of 443) and also re-set the selected certificate in the RAS propertysheet. After restarting RRAS I'm now able to connect to my SSTP VPN.